# How do I code a media query into style=""

Tags: html, css

In CSS, how would I select the `.button` element? I have tried just `.button` but it is not working at all. The only way I can get it to hide is by hardcoding `style="display: none;`

```
    <div id="navBar">
        <nav>
            <li><a class="button">&#9776;</a>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="schedule.php">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.php">Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sponsors.php">Sponsors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bobbykendallracing/"><img src="images/fbicon.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/bobbykendall11?lang=en"><img src="images/ticon.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your css content? Are you using media queries? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I updated the question, I figured something out, but just need help with something else.

Comment: @G.Sto  Your updated question does not make sense at all. If you figured something out please consider posting an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like creating a css class called .only-mobile like this

```
.only-mobile {
    display: none;
}
```

And then using media queries you can change .only-mobile to display in block etc.